# Titanium alloy and https

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am trying to make SSL request, but Titanium keeps rejecting it with a 404 error. The url is correct, here is my code:

```
exports.APIGetRequest = function(url, callback, errorCallback) {
    Ti.API.info('Get Request is called');
    var req = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : callback,
        onerror : errorCallback,
        timeout : 60000,
        validatesSecureCertificate : true

    });
    req.open("GET", url);
    console.log("\n\nAPIGetRequest - Alloy.Globals.authToken:\n" + Alloy.Globals.authToken + "\n\n");
    req.setRequestHeader('AUTHORIZATION', 'Token ' + Alloy.Globals.authToken);
    req.send();
};
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting `validatesSecureCertificate` to true will try to verify CRT if its invalid or expired you will not be able to make request .

set `validatesSecureCertificate` to false , this will keep `httpClient` run over `https` don't worry .

to solve your issue set `validatesSecureCertificate` to false

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I seem to be getting a 404 error when I set it to false.

Comment: check your link output maybe its not exists 404 means page not found this error not related to SSL or https

Comment: Thanks it was a URL issue! :)